# How to correctly serialize embedded struct with String() method to JSON string?

Tags: json, string, go, serialization, format

```
 package main

 import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
 )

 type Ticket struct {
    From string
    To   string
}

func (t Ticket) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s - %s", t.From, t.To)
}

type Passenger struct {
    Name string `json:"Name"`
    Tkt  Ticket `json:"Ticket"`
}

func main() {
    p := Passenger{}
    p.Name = "John"
    p.Tkt.From = "New York"
    p.Tkt.To = "Washington"

    buf, _ := json.Marshal(p)
    fmt.Println(string(buf))
}
```

This code outputs:

```
 {"Name":"John","Ticket":{"From":"New York","To":"Washington"}}
```

But, using `json.Marshal()` method (it's easy and friendly for complex struct), how to make it output like this:

```
 {"Name":"John","Ticket":"New York - Washington"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate the JSON representation of a Go value, the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package checks if the value implements the [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) or the [`encoding.TextMarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextMarshaler) interfaces, and if so, they are used / called (in this order). This is documented at [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

> Marshal traverses the value v recursively. If an encountered value implements the Marshaler interface and is not a nil pointer, Marshal calls its MarshalJSON method to produce JSON. If no MarshalJSON method is present but the value implements encoding.TextMarshaler instead, Marshal calls its MarshalText method and encodes the result as a JSON string.

The `json/encoding` package doesn't care about the `String()` method. So if you want to control the JSON representation / output of your value (the `Ticket` struct), implement `json.Marshaler` on it (in which you may call `String()` to your liking):

```
func (t Ticket) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(`"` + t.String() + `"`), nil
}
```

Then the output will be as you desire:

```
{"Name":"John","Ticket":"New York - Washington"}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/b09uEAqOH_).

**One thing to look out for:** if the `string` produced by `Ticket.String()` would contain a quotation mark `"`, the output would become invalid JSON, or more likely `json.Marshal()` would return an error.

**To take care of such escaping, best / easiest is to use the `json` package itself: tell it to JSON-encode the `string` result of `Ticket.String()`:**

```
func (t Ticket) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(t.String())
}
```

Now if we test it like this:

```
p.Name = "John"
p.Tkt.From = "New\" York" // CONTAINS QUOTE
p.Tkt.To = "Washington"

buf, err := json.Marshal(p)
fmt.Println(string(buf), err)
```

The output will still be a valid JSON (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nROMV6dyri)):

```
{"Name":"John","Ticket":"New\" York - Washington"} <nil>
```

Comment: Wonderful solution. Thank you.

Comment: Incidentally, you can just use `%q` instead of `%s` and it'll quote the string for you.  https://play.golang.org/p/RYhaMM5kpd

Comment: @Kaedys You made me realize I forgot about potential quotes in the input. I updated the question to suggest use of the `json` package itself to take care of those.

Comment: Good call, though the `%q` token to `fmt.Sprintf()` will automatically escape any quotes in the input string as well.

Comment: @Kaedys Yes, in this case both would work. But in general it's best to leave escaping to the `json` package which will handle all cases.